# Python script output in the wrong directory when called from cron

Tags: debian, cron, python

The script `/blah/script.py` has `-rwxr-xr-x  1 root     root` permissions and ownership. The script is:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

with open('blahblah', 'w') as f:
    f.write('hello')
```

With `crontab -e`, I tried:

`0 * * * * /blah/script.py`

It works but the file is created as `/root/blahblah` instead of `/blah/blahblah`. 
How to make the output file in the desired directory (`/blah/blahblah` in this case) without hard coding its name in the .py file? In other words, **how to call a Python script from cron, with the directory where the script is stored as the working directory**?

*Note: This is working but not very nice:  `0 * * * * cd /home/blah && /usr/bin/python script.py`.*

Answer (score 2):

The solution is to add this in the Python script

```
import os, sys
os.chdir(sys.path[0])
```

as explained in the answers of https://stackoverflow.com/q/1432924/1422096.